# Proof global minimum of $x^2+y^4-y^2$

Tags: analysis

Proof global minimum of
$f(x,y)=x^2+y^4-y^2$
is $\frac{1}{2}$ where $f:$ $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
Is my proof attempt correct?

Define $g(y):=f(0,y)$. Differentiating $g$ after $y$ we find $4y^{3}-2y$. By setting $4y^{3}-2y=0$ we find that $y=0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Differentiating again we find $\frac{d}{dy}\frac{dg}{dy}=12y^{2}-2$. $\frac{d}{dy}\frac{dg}{dy}(0)<0$ and $\frac{d}{dy}\frac{dg}{dy}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})>0$ we find that only $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ are a local minimum. Notice that $g$ is continuous and differentiable thus we find that the minimum of the local minimums is the global minimum. Since $f(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=f(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=-\frac{1}{4}$ this is the global minimum of $g$. We also have $f(x,y) \geq g(y) \geq -\frac{1}{4}$ because $x^2$ is always positive. Which yields to the result that $-\frac{1}{4}$ is the global minimum of the function $f$

Comment: Almost perfect. "... because $x^2$ is always positive." NO. Because $x^2$ is never negative.

Comment: I'd like to write $f(x, y) = x^2+(y^2-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}$ to prove the minimum. There's no need of calculus, though.

Comment: this is a smart idea I tried this but I could not succeedty

Comment: It is much easier to see that $$f(x,y)=x^2 + \left(y^2-\frac 12\right)^2-\frac14\ .$$Usually, one has also to "check the boundary" for a minimum, this is **not done** above. Should be done (and can be easily done) to have a complete argumentation.

Comment: @dan_fulea, what do you mean by "boundary".  It looks like there are no restrictions on the domain: $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sometimes, but not in this case, an infimum is taken when values $(x,y)$ have one or both components going to $\pm \infty$ (in a more or less coordinated manner). In such a case, we would have no global minimum at a critical point. At any rate, a full proof going as in the posted solution should mention this aspect. To understand why, just do the same for a function like $x\to exp(-x^2)p(x)$ where $p$ is a polynomial with only positive values on $\Bbb R$. For instance $p(x)=x^4+3x^2+1$. Just plot and do what you did...